# I'm having trouble getting argc and argv from command line into a function call

Tags: c, function, argv

This is the first version of the code. the purpose of it is to take every digit past argc(5) and act as if it was a polynomial. however, it needs to take all input after argc(5) into account. it will then be passed the variable X i will calculate, but for simplicity's sake ill just assign it as 5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

double begin = atof (argv[1]); //start of graph
double end = atof (argv[2]);  //end of graph
double inc = atof (argv[3]); //level of incriments FIXME
double low = atof (argv[4]); // lower section (what?)
double high = atof (argv[5]); //higher section(what?)


// need nested for loop use I total out of loop to get additive number.
// NO NEGATIVE NECESSARY
double sum=0;
double x=5;


printf("argc :%d\n", argc);  //argc counts initialization character
double j=argc-5-2;
printf("initial j %lf\n", j);

for (int i=6; i<argc; i++)
{
        sum = sum + (atof(argv[i]) * pow(x,j));
       j--;

}
printf("%lf\n", sum);



return 0;
}
```

This is the second version of the code, where i put the calculation for x within the function cal calcX i only passed the variable x to the function, which i believe is the problem. what do i have to do so that all instances of argc and argv are passed to the function, as well as the variable x

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

double begin = atof (argv[1]); //start of graph
double end = atof (argv[2]);  //end of graph
double inc = atof (argv[3]); //level of incriments FIXME
double low = atof (argv[4]); // lower section (what?)
double high = atof (argv[5]); //higher section(what?)

double width = (high-low) / inc;
double x=5;

calcX(x);


return 0;
}


void calcX(int argc, char*argv[], double x)
{
double sum=0;
double j=argc-5-2;
printf("initial j %lf\n", j);
for (int i=6; i<argc; i++)
{
        sum = sum + (atof(argv[i]) * pow(x,j));
       j--;
}
printf("%lf\n", sum);



return;
}
```

these are the errors the program gives me, looks pretty standard, but im not sure how to go about fixing it. thanks for your time.

```
$ gcc 2v.c
2v.c: In function ‘main’:
2v.c:17:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘calcX’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 calcX(x);
 ^~~~~
2v.c: At top level:
2v.c:24:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘calcX’
 void calcX(int argc, char*argv[], double x)
      ^~~~~
2v.c:17:1: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘calcX’ was here
 calcX(x);
 ^~~~~
```

also, if the formatting of my question was wrong please let me know what i can do to improve it

Comment: "the purpose of it is to take every digit past argc(5) and act as if it was a polynomial. however, it needs to take all input after argc(5) into account. it will then be passed the variable X i will calculate, but for simplicity's sake ill just assign it as 5.", don't make sense to me, read [ask].

Comment: Open your favorite C book, when you are calling a function you need to pass all its argument, `calcX(argc, argv, x);`

Comment: Try moving the function `calcX()` above `main()`.  That should change the error message you're getting, and provide more insight into what's wrong.

Comment: `calcX` must be declared before you call it. (Old versions of C were looser about this rule, but ignore that.) Add a declaration `void calcX(int argc, char*argv[], double x);` before `main`. Moving the entire definition of `calcX` above that of `main` would be another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here.  First, `calcX` takes three arguments, but you're only passing one:

```
calcX(x);
```

You need to pass `argc` and `argv` as well:

```
calcX(argc, argv, x);
```

Second, you use the function `calcX` before you declare it, so the function is implicitly declared to take an unknown number of arguments and return an `int`.  This conflicts with the actual definition.

To fix this, move the definition of `calcX` above `main`.

Comment: ill put that in in a moment, i forgot the easy way of putting the function before the main, so ill change the code up, ill get back in a bit. thanks so much!